# Two sticky elements on scroll - max width on main container issue

Tags: jquery

I've set up a "sticky" menu element using jQuery which works fine, but I also need to make an additional element sticky, and the tricky part is that this is a floated element - the meta sidebar for a blog item basically - and it needs to be sticky relative to the sticky menu bar I've mentioned. I've been playing about with this and am not sure the neatest way to handle it - here's an attempt on jsfiddle.

The issue here is that the containing div (of the floated blog sidebar) has a max width set, and when you scroll up and the sidebar becomes sticky, the width of the sidebar increases. I'm not too sure why this is happening - any ideas would be appreciated?

Wrapping container CSS:

```
.body {
    margin-top: 50px
    clear: both;
    max-width: 450px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dj06og6z/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dj06og6z/1/) it's not the best solution , but it works well :D

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) 
        {
            var menu = $('.nav-wrapper');
            var blogMeta = $('.blog-meta');
            var stickyOffset = menu.offset().top;
            var maxwidth = blogMeta.width();
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

                if (scroll >= stickyOffset) 
                {
                    menu.addClass('sticky');
                    blogMeta.addClass('sticky');
                    blogMeta.css("max-width",maxwidth+"px");
                }
                else {
                    menu.removeClass('sticky');
                    blogMeta.removeClass('sticky');
                    blogMeta.css("max-width","initial");
                }
            });
        });
```